# How do I change theme in VS Express for Desktop?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to change the theme from light to dark. I know where the settings are to do this but for some reason where the code editor is it doesn't change the theme to dark. How can I fix this?

[Pic of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoYeJ.png)

Comment: You need to select a dark editor color scheme

Answer (score 2):

Use the Tools > Options dialog to set the color theme.

It's the first option under Environment > General.

[image: Options Dialog]

If that doesn't work, search for "theme" by typing it in the options search box and try changing the settings for the Text Editor.

[image: Advanced Options]

You can now change the background color of the text. If you've modified it by yourself previously, click the [Use Defaults] button to revert it.